# Ajax jquery problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a french website
http://techtionary.comeze.com/game.php

This is the link

the signup works(p.s if you enter any user name and password it will let you in)

When I do an ajax request my god damn free hosting adds this string of text to every page.

```
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

This causes my json and html to be unreadable

How do I cut off this string. Also any other suggestion why website is not working.

P.s I asked a question about my website earlier but it was kinda different

Comment: Are you setting content type headers?  I would assume your hosting provider only adds that code to content that is served with the text/html MIME type, which also happens to be the default.  If you try setting a content type header to `application/json` you might find it works correctly.

Comment: you can also try and use mod_rewrite so instead of calling a .php script when you do the ajax request, you would call a .json file

Comment: but in my json is delivered from php

Answer (score 3):

Using `header('Content-Type: application/json');` is not enough for 000webhost.

Calling `die;` at the end of the script removes unwanted html from AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dataFilter option in [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to filter the response text. Use this function to process the response text and strip down the add content and return the processed value.

You can try with this instead of `load()`

```
var regex = new RegExp("\<h2\>.+\</h2\>");
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "score.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    dataFilter : function(responseText, dataType){
        return regex.exec(responseText)[0];
    }
}).success(function(result){
    $("#points").html(result);
});
```

You can use the following script to debug

```
var regex = new RegExp("\<h2\>.+\</h2\>");
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "score.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    dataFilter : function(responseText, dataType){
                a = responseText;
        console.log("filter");
        console.log(responseText);
        return regex.exec(responseText)[0];
    }
}).success(function(){
    console.log("success");
    console.log(arguments);
}).error(function(){
    console.log("failure");
    console.log(arguments);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue recently as i was testing a small website for a client here is what i did:

since the ad is consistent and always the same, i return the data as text:

```
req.responseText;
```

i look for the the end of the add message : ended in `</iframe>` in my case and replace it with  a blank string;

```
var outMsg = xhr.responseText;
var index = (outMsg.indexOf("</iframe>") == -1 )? outMsg.length : outMsg.indexOf("</iframe>"); // my case ended with iframe, yours <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
outMsg = outMsg.substring(0,index);
outMsg = outMsg.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, ""); // clear leading white space if any
```

now you can eval your ajax or convert it to any data type you want :)

Comment: i just checked your page and in your case you will substring from the begining of the added text till the end of the document

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `.load()`, you could try adding another 'selector' to the method to only return a fragment of the page. Go here http://api.jquery.com/load/ and read the section titled "Loading Page Fragments."

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

So to answer your question on how to set the content type header, it's nice and easy.  Headers have to be output before any real content, so anywhere before you start echoing/printing your json output just add the line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This tells both the server and the browser that the content that's coming up has the json type and unless the sysadmin for your hosting provider is a total moron, that shouldn't get tagged with that analytics code.

You can use firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome to make sure the header is being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the 'free host' doesn't seem to mind making your page's html invalid - that suggests you should not expect your pages to work reliably on this host.  Try a non-free host - they work better.